# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException not firing

Tags: c#, appdomain

I have a pre application start method that bootstraps my application. (ASP.NET 5)

It looks like this:

```
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;

        ConfigureDryIoc(Container);

        ConfigureAppInsights(Container.Resolve<ApplicationConfiguration>());

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Something went wrong");
```

For some reason, the CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException-delegate is not called, given a exception been thrown at the end of the method.

Why does the delegate doesn't get called? How do I get this working?

Comment: The delegate does not get called probably because this is not an unhandled exception.  The code you are showing is probably executed from some context that contains a `try{ } catch { }`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This method is triggered via a PreApplicationStartupAttribute so as far is I know there is no try catch block in that code?

Comment: I am not sure, and that's why this is a comment and not an answer.